# Operators can't be applied to java string

Tags: java, string

I am writing a program that takes the loan amount, interest rate, and total paid from a text file. It is supposed to update the interest rate to total interest and the same for total paid. Then it is supposed to calculate the monthly payments.

I keep getting the error operators can't be applied to java string for the calculations including loan. I'm guessing this is because you can't use strings in calculations? Maybe i'm wrong. I am stumped.

Example input:

```
56750.00 .065 72.00
43675.00 .075 48.00
64950.00 .045 36.00
24799.00 .085 48.00
```

My code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class DB4
{
    static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        String loan;
        int Count = 0;
        double interest = 0;
        double Numberofmonths = 0;
        double totint;
        double totpay;
        double monthly;

        Scanner inFile= new Scanner(new FileReader("Project4InData.txt"));

        PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter("Project4.out");

        while (inFile.hasNext())
        {
            loan = inFile.next();
            interest = inFile.nextDouble();
            Numberofmonths = inFile.nextDouble();

            // calcs

            totint = interest * loan;

            totpay = totint + loan;

            monthly = loan / 12;

            outFile.print("Loan Amount: " + loan);
            outFile.print(" ");
            outFile.println("Interest: " + totint);
            outFile.print(" ");
            outFile.println("Total paid: " + totpay);
            outFile.print(" ");
            outFile.println("Monthly payment: " + monthly);
        }

        inFile.close();
        outFile.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: so why don't you change `loan` to be another variable type e.g. double?

Comment: The value in the file looks like a `double` to me, why make `loan` a `String`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`loan` is a string, so `interest * loan` doesn't make sense.

To realize why it doesn't make sense to apply `*` to a string, consider what `"abc" * 2` or `"def" * "ghi"` would mean. (Absolutely nothing, which is why Java doesn't allow you to perform those operations on `string` objects).

You *can* apply `+` to strings, but it doesn't do addition, it does concatenation.

Same logic applies to the `/` operator.

Make `loan` a `double`.